# discord.py Как создавать глобальные Slash-команды?

Tags: python, discord.py, discord, discord-api

Я пытался найти нормальный ответ на вопрос в интернете, но так ничего и не понял. На данный момент у меня есть вот этот код для команд:

```py
# ...
@bot.tree.command(
    name='help',
    description='Команда для помощи по боту'
)
@app_commands.describe(command='Указывает, по какой конкретной команде нужна помощь')
async def cmd_help(interaction, command: str = ''):
    await cmd_handlers['help'](interaction, interaction.command.name, [command], True)

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

@bot.tree.command(
    name='restart',
    description='Команда для перезапуска бота',
    guild=discord.Object(id=1096677139450966036)
)
async def cmd_restart(interaction):
    await cmd_handlers['restart'](interaction, interaction.command.name, [], True)

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

@bot.tree.command(
    name='приветствовать',
    description='Команда для того, чтобы поприветствовать кому-нибудь'
)
@app_commands.describe(target='Устанавливает цель для приветствия')
async def cmd_hello(interaction, target: str):
    await cmd_handlers['приветствовать'](interaction, interaction.command.name, [target], True)
# ...
```

Словарь `cmd_handlers` включает в себя:

```py
from commands import help, restart, hello
cmd_handlers = {
    'help': help.handler,
    'restart': restart.handler,
    'приветствовать': hello.handler
}
```

Однако, важно не это, а то, что единственное, что появляется, - команда /restart, остальное же не появляется:
[image: Скриншот команд от бота]

Как раз для этой команды указан `guild`, однако, для остальных команд этот самый `guild` не нужен. Так как же сделать Slash-команду глобальной? На заметку: я пробовал делать для них `guild`, и они таинственным образом появлялись в том списке, но стоило мне его убрать, как всё тут же пропало...

Здесь я синхронизирую команды:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    printE('Синхронизируем Slash-команды...')
    synced = await bot.tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=1096677139450966036))
    printE(f'Синхронизировано {len(synced)} команд!')
    printE('Бот запущен!')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне не следовало указывать `guild` при синхронизации команд:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    printE('Синхронизируем Slash-команды...')
    synced = await bot.tree.sync('--здесь был удалён параметр guild--')
    printE(f'Синхронизировано {len(synced)} команд!')
    printE('Бот запущен!')
```

Итог: невнимательность – всему проблема